# Have you ever used IFrame Shims on UL tags?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, shim

I ahve a menu structure that uses UL and LI elements to drop down from a main menu.  The problem i am having (of course) is in IE6 where the menu drops behind SELECT elements despite the z-index.  I have tried adding an IFram shim to the UL which contains the LI elements which are the menu items.  The problem is the Shim sits on top of the UL instead of behind it despite the fact the shim has a lesser z-index than the UL element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem we were seeing was caused by a "wrapper" div that the page content was in having position:relative.  Once we removed this from that container div the shim placed behind the ul but over the drop down (select).

Answer (score 1):

Someone has [made a fix](http://www.fabien-molinet.fr/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogsection&id=8&Itemid=9) that uses the [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) library to do all of this automatically. It's worth taking a look,